# How to fix while loop within function?

Tags: python, function, loops, random, while-loop

My code works, and asks to name the file, and how many numbers. But it just keeps asking for numbers, and if I put zero then it does what it is supposed to do. any help at all is appreciated very much. I just don't know how to fix the code, and it is really bugging me.

```
import random
def generateRandomNumber(myfile):
    try:
        fileToBeWrittenTo = open(myfile,"w")
        numberOfRandomNumbers = int(input("How many numbers" + \
                                      " should the random file hold?:" ))
    except Exception as potentialError:
        print("An error has occured:", potentialError )
    else:
        for randomNumberCount in range(1, numberOfRandomNumbers + 1 ):
            randomNumber = generateRandomNumber(myfile)
            fileToBeWrittenTo.write(str( randomNumber ) + '\n' )
        print( numberOfRandomNumbers, "numbers have been written" + \
               " to the file ")
    finally:
        fileToBeWrittenTo.close()
        print("\nEnd of program")
    displayNumber(myfile)
    randomNumber = random.randint(1,500)
    return randomNumber

def main():
    myfile = str(input("Enter file name here "))
    with open(myfile, 'w+') as f:
        generateRandomNumber(myfile)

    return f
    myfile.close    

def displayNumber(myfile):
    try:
        myfile = open(myfile,'r')
        total = 0
        NORN = 0
        Avg = 0
        line = myfile.readline()
        while line != "":
            randomNumber = int(line)
            total += randomNumber
            NORN += 1
            Avg = total / NORN
            print( randomNumber )
        line = myfile.readline()
    except IOError:
        print("Problem with file being opened")
    else:
        print("The average of the numbers is " + str(Avg))
        print("The total of all the numbers is " + str(total)+\
          "\nThere are " + str(NORN)+\
          " in the file")
        myfile.close()
    finally:
        print("End of program")

main()
```

Comment: Please fix your python indentation

Answer (score 0):

The `generateRandomNumber` function calls itself recursively in the `randomNumber = generateRandomNumber(myfile)` statement, which is skipped if you input a 0.

Also, your `main` contains an unused `with open` and the `myfile.close` statement is neither executed nor needed. Try shortening it.

```
def main():
    myfile = str(input("Enter file name here "))
    generateRandomNumber(myfile)
```

You can also simplify the `generateRandomNumber` and `displayNumber` functions significantly by using [with open](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files).

> It is good practice to use the *with* keyword when dealing with file
>   objects. The advantage is that the file is properly closed after its
>   suite finishes, even if an exception is raised at some point. Using
>   *with* is also much shorter than writing equivalent try-finally blocks

Finally, `displayNumber` contains an infinite loop, try indenting the second `line = myfile.readline()` one step or rewrite the function to read the full file at once and use a simple `for` loop.

```
with open(myfile) as myfilehandle:
    lines = myfilehandle.readlines()

for line in lines:
    # do things
```

Comment: So I fixed that. I got rid of it. and now the code works, but when I put a number in it turns to an ifinite loop

Comment: If I put a 0 in, it does not go as an ifinite loop. Do I need to get rid of the randomNumber = generateRandomNumber(myfile)  completly or modify it?

Comment: It looks like you are keeping `myfile` open by switching between `with open` statements and regular `open` statements. The `with open` in `main` will not close the file until the function returns.

Comment: So I assume I need to change it to a regular open.

Comment: I have updated my answer with an example `main`. You probably should simplify `generateRandomNumber` by using `with open` to make the code easier to follow.

Comment: so even with shortening the main, it still goes into an infinite loop.

Comment: Try replacing the `try/except/else/finally` statement by using `with open` only when writing to the file, removing the `fileToBeWrittenTo.close()` entirely, and using `try/except` only when casting your input to `int`.

Comment: The source of the infinite loop is inside `displayNumber`, in the `while line != ""` loop. `line` is never changed within it so it loops forever.

Answer (score 0):

using `try-except-else-finally` is good but I see it make you confused, try to learn `try-except` first.

you have no ending loop in

```
def generateRandomNumber(myfile):
    ....
            randomNumber = generateRandomNumber(myfile)
```

and

```
while line != "":
    ....
    print( randomNumber )
line = myfile.readline()
```

it should be

```
while line != "":
    ....
    print( randomNumber )
    line = myfile.readline()
```

And here your working code

```
import random

def generateRandomNumber():
    randomNumber = random.randint(1,500)
    return randomNumber

def writeRandom(myfile):
    try:
        fileToBeWrittenTo = open(myfile, "w")
        numberOfRandomNumbers = int(input("How many numbers" + \
                                      " should the random file hold?:" ))
    except Exception as potentialError:
        print("An error has occured:", potentialError )
    else:
        for randomNumberCount in range(1, numberOfRandomNumbers + 1 ):
            randomNumber = generateRandomNumber()
            fileToBeWrittenTo.write(str( randomNumber ) + '\n' )
        print( numberOfRandomNumbers, "numbers have been written" + \
               " to the file ")
        fileToBeWrittenTo.close()
        displayNumber(myfile)
    finally:
        print("\nEnd of program")

def main():
    myfile = str(input("Enter file name here "))
    writeRandom(myfile)  

def displayNumber(myfile):
    try:
        my_file = open(myfile,'r')
        total = 0
        NORN = 0
        Avg = 0
        line = my_file.readline()
        while line != "":
            randomNumber = int(line)
            total += randomNumber
            NORN += 1
            Avg = total / NORN
            print( randomNumber )
            line = my_file.readline()
    except IOError:
        print("Problem with file being opened")
    else:
        print("The average of the numbers is " + str(Avg))
        print("The total of all the numbers is " + str(total)+\
          "\nThere are " + str(NORN)+\
          " in the file")
        my_file.close()
    finally:
        print("End of program")

main()
```